# Why type inference failed in Scala when using implicit conversion on return value of Option.getOrElse?

Tags: scala

For example I have a class *Value* and a implicit function convert string to Value:

```
case class Value(v: String)

implicit def strToValue(s: String): Value = Value(s)
```

And here is a trait which has a method returns Value:

```
trait ReturnValue {
  def f: Value
}
```

Because the implicit conversion exists, I can implement method *f* by just return a String literal:

```
object Obj1 extends ReturnValue {
  override def f: Value = "123"
}
```

And of course return a variable of type String just works fine:

```
object Obj2 extends ReturnValue {
  override def f: Value = {
    val v = Some("123").getOrElse("234")
    v
  }
}
```

But when I trying to use the result of Option.getOrElse directly as the return value:

```
object Obj3 extends ReturnValue {
  override def f: Value = Some("123").getOrElse("234")  // Compilation error: type mismatch
}
```

A compilation error occurred:

```
Error:(23, 50) type mismatch;
 found   : java.io.Serializable
 required: Entry.Value
   override def f: Value = Some("123").getOrElse("234") // Compilation error: type mismatch
```

It seems that type inference here is failed. Type *String* is not inferred, and then the implicit conversion cannot be matched. (Full file is [here](https://gist.github.com/andwxh/5576e7982aae1559b30b3978f7bc1d39))

I have tried other functions which have type parameter, such as "map", they all works perfectly.

Why is the Option.getOrElse so special that type inference failed here?

Comment: Interesting. These variants do work: `override def f: Value = Some("123": Value).getOrElse("234")` and `override def f: Value = None.getOrElse("234")` and even `override def f: Value = Some("123").get `.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I usually solve this problem by type-casting the method `def f: Value = Some("123").getOrElse[String]("234")`, to ensure that the conversion is done at the last possible moment. I believe the issue is related to the fact that `getOrElse` as a call-by-name argument, which must interact wierdly with the type inference and the implicit conversion resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This variants leads to the same compile error, and probably shows how compiler deconstructs the expression:

```
object Obj3 extends ReturnValue {
  override def f: Value = {
    val v = Some("123") // is of type Some(String)
    v.getOrElse("234": Value)  // Compilation error: type mismatch
  }
}
```

Same error can also be achieved without any traits, with following simple repro:

```
case class Value(v: String)

implicit def strToValue(s: String): Value = Value(s)

val vs  = Some("123")

val v: Value = vs.getOrElse("234")
```

It seems the compiler applies the conversion to `Value` on the argument of `getOrElse`, instead of on its result. The fact is does can be confirmed with output with enabled `scalacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-Xprint-types", "-Xprint:typer")` (cleaned a bit - deleted obviously unrelated annotations):

> private[this] val v: Value =
>
> vs.getOrElse{[B >: String](default: => B)B}[java.io.Serializable]{(default: => java.io.Serializable)java.io.Serializable}(  **strToValue{(s: String)Value}("234"{String("234")}){Value}** ){

I think the inference works as follows:

- `vs` type is known as `Some[String]`
- `getOrElse` declaration is `def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B` (`A` is `String` here)
- compilers infers the `B` as `Value`, as this is the expected result type of the expression.
- the most specific supertype of `Value` and `String` is `Serializable`

You can also note how it behaves when you remove the implicit conversion completely. The error for `val v: Value = vs.getOrElse("234")` is then: **type mismatch;
 found   : String("234")
 required: Value**

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a compiler bug. Here's an example showing the odd behavior.

```
case class ValString(string: String)
object ValString {
  implicit def string2ValString(string: String): ValString = ValString(string)
}

case class ValThing( one: ValString, two: ValString, three: ValString, four: ValString, five: ValString)

val opt = Option("aString")
val x = ValThing(
  if(opt.isEmpty) "" else opt.get,
  opt.fold("")(identity),
  opt.orElse(Option("")).get,
  opt.getOrElse(""): String,
  ValString(opt.getOrElse(""))
)
```

The above all works, however

```
val x = ValThing( opt.getOrElse(""), .... )
```

fails because it interprets the output of the getOrElse as a Serializable